# Searching [tag.] causes the description for [tag] to show but not any questions

Tags: bug, search, search-box

I recently discovered that entering `[tag.]` (with one or more `.`s) in the search field causes the tag description for `[tag]` to show up, but not any questions.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript.. yields:

[image]

While https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript yields:

[image]

In my eyes, there are two ways to fix this: Nothing, including the tag description, shows up, or, the questions also appear. I'm assuming this isn't [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign).

Comment: I mean, what harm does it do? It's such a small thing, that there's no point in fixing it. Maybe is is intentional.